# How to pass sliderInput values to params$ variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have a small parameterized Rmarkdown example and am trying to pass the range of values to a variable inside a dplyr call but is failing. The params$maxprice only takes the first value from the slider control but the second value gets ignored. Besides that, the graphic generated defaults to zero instead of the first value of the sliderInput control. How can I pass both parameters from the slider to `params$maxprice`? See below:

````
---
title: "Wine"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date())`"
output:
 html_document:
params:
  glimpse: FALSE
  country:
    label: "Country"
    value: [US]
    input: select
    choices: [US, France, Italy, Argentina]
    multiple: TRUE
  variety: 
    label: "Variety"
    value: ["Cabernet Sauvignon", "Chardonnay"]
    choices: ["Cabernet Sauvignon", "Chardonnay", "Merlot", "Sauvignon Blanc", "Malbec"]
    multiple: TRUE
  maxprice:
    label: "Max Price"
    input: slider
    min: 0
    max: 1000
    value: [25,50]
    step: 1
---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library('here')
    library('tidyverse')
       
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width = 4, fig.height = 4, fig.path=here('Output'))
    
    wine_ratings <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-05-28/winemag-data-130k-v2.csv")
    
    ## Subset to varieties of interest
    wine_ratings <- wine_ratings %>% 
      filter(variety %in% params$variety,
             country %in% params$country,
             !is.na(price),
             price < params$maxprice) ###How to pass the sliderInput parameters to price?
    ```
    ```{r}
    ggplot(wine_ratings, aes(x=points, y=price)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      facet_wrap(~ variety) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, params$maxprice)) +
      ggtitle("Wine Price")
    ```
````

Comment: Can you just use `params$maxprice[1]` for the first value and `params$maxprice[2]` for the second?

Comment: I tried that earlier and did not work. I tried: `params$maxprice[1] & params$maxprice[2]`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to use the two values to do?

Comment: The range of values that I select from the slider, I want them to be passed on to params$maxprice. For example, if I select values on the slider from 200 to 400, I want only those values to be displayed on the graph.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for checking into it.